# Remote desktop connection to WinPE 8.0

Tags: windows, remote-desktop, rdp, windows-8

I'm trying to find the way to configure WinPE (Windows Preinstallation Environment) 8.0 for RDP (Remote Desktop Protocol) connection.
Actually I need to connect over RDP to running WinPE based on Windows 8.

Thanks for any help!

Comment: Why? What is the larger problem you're trying to solve?

Comment: Connect from my home PC to running WinPE over RDP

Comment: You didn't answer my question. **why?**

Comment: To have ability to work with running app on WinPE remotely.

Comment: WinPE isn't meant to be an application runtime environment like that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately, if you're only willing to accept RDP/Terminal services, you're out of luck.  [Microsoft says](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc766093%28v=ws.10%29.aspx):

> Windows PE cannot act as a file server or terminal server. (Remote
>   Desktop is unsupported.)

A former minion of mine once experimented with embedding VNC into PE as part of debugging Altiris client imaging.  [TechNet also suggests VNC](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/ec0c33a7-16c7-4758-b90e-5dfbc3ed5ea1/winpe-and-rdpremote-server?forum=mdt).  I've seen it work personally, and it's probably your best bet.

Comment: Thanks for help,
I've already seen these links.
First and last ones are not about ordinary "Remote Desktop Connection" way.
Second one is about thin client, but I need connect to WinPE, not from

Comment: Maybe we are not on the same way. I need to have ability connect to WinPE by regular RDP way, like this [link](http://wp-hub.in.ua/winpe.png)

Answer (score 0):

You need the DART version and tools which give you the remote session viewer.  See http://www.deploymentresearch.com/Research/tabid/62/EntryId/36/Software-Assurance-Pays-Off-Remote-Connection-to-WinPE-during-MDT-SCCM-deployments.aspx for an example.

Comment: I originally had that link but the OP said no to it because it's "not about ordinary 'Remote Desktop Connection' way."  I should have left it in my answer.  :)

Answer (score 0):

You **CAN** add Powershell, **WMI** and **CIM** Cmdlets. Also **Bitlocker Cmdlets** and **Disk-Storage Management** Cmdlets to Win-PE though... Powershell is a little crippled though but still works great! You are limited also by the size of the scratch space on your PE Image for commands you need. I added Sysinternals tools which fit nicely. :(

If you can't accomplish whatever your Admin tasks are through WMI/CIM, or Powershell... You're probably not running the right OS.

Win-PE is designed mainly for Preparing the System prior to OS installation. Also for "Capturing" OS Images.

Answer (score -3):

Hate to break the news to the person above who says that windows rdp connection is not accepted in windows pe. Because literally 5 minutes ago i grabbed an rdp shortcut off my server that connects to windows multipoint server 2011. works like a charm!  as far as this goes, im trying add that file to windows pe as a desktop shortcut I will be more than happy to keep you posted on how this can be done. but more than possible to click an rdp connection off of a server drive and run it, if it does not connect to \SERVEREXAMPLE

right click it and select Edit, then type the ip address of the server.

if you have to grab a thumb drive and place it on desktop. only issue is you have to do this every time a machine boots up. as far as my network setup is, i have 2 NAT the one underneath my head NAT is windows server 2008 R2 with DHCP and DNS Server. This has windows deployment services installed as well. Its a setup for 2 separate networks. So far no issues at all.

Comment: This site is not a forum - it's a QA site, meaning that an answer should be the full and complete answer, not an ongoing dialogue.